# problem installing netbeans on freeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I want to install netbeans on my freeBSD7.2 machine.I followed the instructions listed in 
http://typo.submonkey.net/articles/2007/7/13/netbeans-on-freebsd
But, when i try the third step, which is running the netbeans using "./netbeans/bin/netbeans" i found the following error
"etc/netbeans.cluster" file cann't be found.
What do u think could be the reason. I can't figure it out, plz help me.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Is the error as you posted it or is it "/etc/netbeans.cluster" (with a slash at the beginning)?

Comment: It should be etc/netbeans.cluster (no leading slash).  The etc referenced is under the Netbeans directory.

Answer (score 3):

To install NetBeans under FreeBSD use ports:

```
su
cd /usr/ports/java/netbeans/ && make install clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not install it from the Ports?